# C++ error: undefined reference to 'clock_gettime' and 'clock_settime'

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu, posix, time.h

I am pretty new to Ubuntu, but I can't seem to get this to work.  It works fine on my school computers and I don't know what I am not doing.  I have checked **usr/include** and time.h is there just fine.  Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    timespec time1, time2;
    int temp;
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID, &time1);
    //do stuff here
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID, &time2);
    return 0;
}
```

I am using CodeBlocks as my IDE to build and run as well. Any help would be great, thank you.

Comment: You often need `-D_XOPEN_SOURCE=600`, too. Also see [GCC with -std=c99 complains about not knowing struct timespec](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3875197/608639).

Answer (score 304, accepted):

Add `-lrt` to the end of g++ command line. This links in the librt.so "Real Time" shared library.

Comment: that works if I compile manually - any idea how I automate that in codeblocks?

Comment: try Project -> Build Options -> Linker Settings ; then add library rt

Comment: Your suggestion works fine for me..I am new to `C`...what does the `-lrt`do ?

Comment: @noufal It commands the linker to search for rt library and use it to resolve undefined symbols,  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linker_(computing)

Comment: Sorry to noob it up in this joint, but could you use that in a complete example, somehing like `g++ -o main -lrt main.cpp` does not work for me

Comment: @puk Try putting `-lrt` after `main.cpp` - order of shared libraries matter - see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12272890/279308) or [that](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5571596/279308) for more details

Answer (score 44):

example:

```
c++ -Wall filefork.cpp -lrt -O2
```

For `gcc` version 4.6.1, `-lrt` must be **after** *filefork.cpp* otherwise you get a link error.

Some older `gcc` version doesn't care about the position.

Comment: Thank you, the `-lrt` not being in the right position was causing me a headache. Is there any motivation for this crazy (well, many say criminal) setting?

Comment: @Avio - the order matters for historical reasons. Compilers used to just process each argument in order. Because libraries are "soft" references, as opposed to "hard" references in the `*.o` arguments, the library functions are ignored *unless* they are referenced previously, which means, to the left.

Answer (score 38):

Since glibc version 2.17, the library linking `-lrt` is no longer required.

The `clock_*` are now part of the main C library. You can see the [change history of glibc 2.17](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=commitdiff;h=6e6249d0b461b952d0f544792372663feb6d792a;ds=sidebyside) where this change was done explains the reason for this change:

```
+* The `clock_*' suite of functions (declared in <time.h>) is now available
+  directly in the main C library.  Previously it was necessary to link with
+  -lrt to use these functions.  This change has the effect that a
+  single-threaded program that uses a function such as `clock_gettime' (and
+  is not linked with -lrt) will no longer implicitly load the pthreads
+  library at runtime and so will not suffer the overheads associated with
+  multi-thread support in other code such as the C++ runtime library.
```

If you decide to upgrade glibc, then you can check the [compatibility tracker of glibc](http://upstream.rosalinux.ru/versions/glibc.html) if you are concerned whether there would be any issues using the newer glibc.

To check the glibc version installed on the system, run the command:

```
ldd --version
```

(Of course, if you are using old glibc (<2.17) then you will still need `-lrt`.)

Answer (score 27):

I encountered the same error.  My linker command did have the rt library included `-lrt` which is correct and it was working for a while. After re-installing Kubuntu it stopped working.

A separate forum thread suggested the `-lrt` needed to come after the project object files.
Moving the `-lrt` to the end of the command fixed this problem for me although I don't know the details of why.

Comment: Quoting twkm from ircnet:


the linker only maintains a list of symbols needed.  once a file's symbols have been searched, only what it needs is kept, what it provides is discarded and it moves to the next filename.
so left to right, but very forgetful.