# Using strptime under cygwin64 on Windows 8 in CodeBlocks

Tags: c++, c, cygwin

I am trying to compile some code originally written in linux on my Windows machine. I have Cygwin installed and setup for use within CodeBlocks, and it works mostly. All except a call to strptime, which greets me with "error: 'strptime' was not delcared in this scope." I've been googling for a while now to no avail, please could someone explain what might be wrong? I've tried including time.h but no luck.

```
#ifndef _XOPEN_SOURCE
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE
#endif

#include <ctime>
#include <cstring>

class Date {
private:
  struct tm _tm;
  string strform;

  static void set_zero(struct tm &_tm) {
    memset(&_tm, '\0', sizeof(struct tm));
    //    _tm.hour = 0;
  }

  time_t make_time() {
    return mktime(&_tm);
  }

public:
  Date() {
    time_t current = time(NULL);
    _tm = *gmtime(&current);
    char buffer[1024];
    strftime(buffer, 1024, "%b %e %Y", &_tm);
    strform = buffer;
  }

  Date(time_t current) {
    _tm = *gmtime(&current);
    char buffer[1024];
    strftime(buffer, 1024, "%b %e %Y", &_tm);
    strform = buffer;
  }

  Date(string _strform) {
    strform = _strform;
    set_zero(_tm);
    char *result = strptime(strform.c_str(), "%b %e %Y", &_tm);
    assert(result);
    char buffer[1024];
    strftime(buffer, 1024, "%b %e %Y", &_tm);
    strform = buffer;
    //cout << "strform = " << strform << endl;
    //    cout << "length = " << result - strform.c_str() << endl;
    //    cout << "day = " << _tm.tm_mday << endl;
    //    cout << "month = " << _tm.tm_mon << endl;
    //    cout << "year = " << _tm.tm_year << endl;
    //    char buffer[1024];
    //    strftime(buffer, 1024, "%b %e %Y   %H:%M:%S", &_tm);
    //    cout << "buffer = " << buffer << endl;
  }

  Date operator-(int days) {
    return Date(make_time() - days*86400 );
  }

  time_t operator-(Date &other) {
    return (make_time() - other.make_time())/86400.0;
  }

  bool operator<=(Date &other) {
    return make_time() <= other.make_time();
  }

  bool operator<(Date &other) {
    return make_time() < other.make_time();
  }

  bool operator>=(Date &other) {
    return make_time() >= other.make_time();
  }

  time_t to_seconds() {
    return make_time();
  }

  friend ostream &operator<< (ostream &out, const Date &d) {
    return out << d.strform;
  }

  static Date today() {
    return Date();
  }

  string to_string() const {
    return strform;
  }

  const char *to_cstring() const {
    return strform.c_str();
  }
};
```

Comment: `strptime` is not a standard C function. In my projects I use a public domain implementation of it.

Answer (score 3):

[See this answer on XOPEN_SOURCE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5378778/what-does-d-xopen-source-do-mean). I had some luck getting strptime to compile by adding `add_definitions(-D_XOPEN_SOURCE=700)` to my CMakeLists.txt. That ended letting strptime be found by the compiler, by turning features on in the header.

Answer (score 0):

This error message means that function is not declared at the point it is found. It looks like `strptime()` is declared in the `time.h` file in Cygwin (at least in v1.7.25) so simply add:

```
 #include <time.h>
```

to your source file. Note that `strptime()` is not a standard C function.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I did try that beforehand but still was met with the same message.

Comment: I would suggest grepping the include files to make sure you actually have `strptime()` on your system. Something like `grep -r strptime /usr/include/*`.

Answer (score 0):

This only happens in C++11 and above. It looks like `__STRICT_ANSI__` is being set and strptime() is not defined under that.  A workaround is to undef `__STRICT_ANSI__` as follows.

```
#ifdef __CYGWIN__
#undef __STRICT_ANSI__
#endif
```