# strptime does not works with timezone format specifier

Tags: c, timezone, unix-timestamp, strptime

I am new to c and trying out on `strptime` function, which converts string time to structure `tm`. After converting i am not getting right time. everything is fine but year is displaying wrong(default year 1900).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main()
{
    struct tm tm;
    char *pszTemp = "Mon Apr 25 09:53:00 IST 2016";
    char szTempBuffer[256];

    memset(&tm, 0, sizeof(struct tm));
    memset(szTempBuffer, 0, sizeof(szTempBuffer));
    strptime(pszTemp, "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Z %Y", &tm);
    strftime(szTempBuffer, sizeof(szTempBuffer), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", &tm);

    printf("Last Boot Time after parsed = %s\n", szTempBuffer);

    return 0;
}
```

> Output : 1900-04-25 09:53:00

Comment: Have you checked what [`strptime`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strptime.3.html) returns? So that it doesn't return a `NULL` pointer?

Comment: Did you tried to compile with `-Wall` option?

Comment: @LPs: it didn't work.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: it returns NULL. could you tell the reason/solution??

Comment: What is your platform? I tried on debian 8.2 gcc 4.9 and all works well.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see into `time.h` source file you have to declare `__USE_XOPEN` and `_GNU_SOURCE` before to include `time.h`

```
#define __USE_XOPEN
#define _GNU_SOURCE

#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main()
{
    struct tm tm;
    char *pszTemp = "Mon Apr 25 09:53:00 IST 2016";
    char szTempBuffer[256];

    memset(&tm, 0, sizeof(struct tm));
    memset(szTempBuffer, 0, sizeof(szTempBuffer));
    strptime(pszTemp, "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Z %Y", &tm);
    strftime(szTempBuffer, sizeof(szTempBuffer), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", &tm);

    printf("Last Boot Time after parsed = %s\n", szTempBuffer);

    return 0;
}
```

You can also simply add definition into you gcc command:

```
gcc -Wall test.c -o test -D__USE_XOPEN -D_GNU_SOURCE
```

**EDIT**

[This historical SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5378778/what-does-d-xopen-source-do-mean) gives all infos about those defines.

Comment: Can you explain why is that necessary? Edit: Thank you.

Comment: @2501 [This historical SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5378778/what-does-d-xopen-source-do-mean) gives all infos about those defines.

Answer (score 0):

The %Z doesn't work for strptime, only for strftime. strptime stops reading after %Z. Therefore the 2016 is missing.

http://linux.die.net/man/3/strptime

If you use glibc it should work.

Comment: play a little bit around with the position of %Z and 2016 and you can see it