# Why is _LARGEFILE_SOURCE defined in stdio.h when compiling with g++ but not gcc?

Tags: c++, c, gcc, large-files, large-file-support

If the following code is compiled with gcc lfs.c -o lfs, it prints nothing.  However, if it is compiled with g++ lfs.c -o lfs, it prints "_LARGEFILE_SOURCE defined by stdio.h!".

```
#ifdef _LARGEFILE_SOURCE
int largefile_defined_at_start = 1;
#else
int largefile_defined_at_start = 0;
#endif

// This defines _LARGEFILE_SOURCE, but only in C++!
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
#ifdef _LARGEFILE_SOURCE
  if (!largefile_defined_at_start)
    printf("_LARGEFILE_SOURCE defined by stdio.h!");
#endif
  return 0;
}
```

In either case, _LARGEFILE_SOURCE is not defined by the compiler:

```
gcc -dM -E - < /dev/null |grep _LARGEFILE_SOURCE |wc -l
0
g++ -dM -E - < /dev/null |grep _LARGEFILE_SOURCE |wc -l
0
```

Why is stdio.h defining _LARGEFILE_SOURCE when GCC is invoked via the g++ frontend?

Comment: What platform are you programming on? Are you programming against the glibc?

Comment: `_LARGEFILE_SOURCE` is obsolete anyways, why do you think you need it? Legacy code?

Comment: @BaummitAugen It is not obsolete. If you compile a C program on i386 Linux, you get a 32 bit `off_t` by default. `_LARGEFILE_SOURCE` is kinda needed.

Comment: @FUZxxl It is obsolete if you just use `#define _FILE_OFFSET_BITS 64` instead.

Comment: @DietrichEpp Which is a non-standard feature-test macro as opposed to the standard `_LARGEFILE_SOURCE`.

Comment: Cannot reproduce with g++6 on Arch btw.

Comment: @BaummitAugen: You are probably compiling for 64-bit.

Comment: @DietrichEpp Indeed, I was not aware that mattered. Thx.

Comment: @FUZxxl `_FILE_OFFSET_BITS 64` is standard POSIX afaik, just like `_LARGEFILE_SOURCE`. Though the latter is called historical and *"New programs
          should not employ this macro; defining _XOPEN_SOURCE as just
          described or defining _FILE_OFFSET_BITS with the value 64 is the
          preferred mechanism to achieve the same result."* http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/feature_test_macros.7.html

Comment: Related to: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5378778/315052

Comment: Names starting with underscore are implementation-specific and reserved for internal use. You must not use them unless explicitly allowed by the implementation. I doubt the documentation allows this. Also C and C++ are different languages. You would not expect `for c in "12345":` to be legal in C either.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because g++ defines `_GNU_SOURCE`, which basically implies all other feature macros, such as `_LARGEFILE_SOURCE`.  These additional macros are defined when the `<features.h>` header is included, and most system header files include `<features.h>` very early in the file.  The fact that `_GNU_SOURCE` is predefined is a continual source of frustration for people who want to write portable C++ code.

I believe you can simply:

```
#undef _GNU_SOURCE
```

However, this will break libstdc++.  Ouch!  What a pain!  This all stems from one of the biggest design flaws in C++, which is the fact that `#include` is basically textual inclusion.  Since most of libstdc++ is defined (not just declared!) in header files, this means that they contaminate your program with `_GNU_SOURCE`.

If you need to access an interface hidden by `_GNU_SOURCE` (such as `strerror_r`, for example, which is completely broken by `_GNU_SOURCE`) then you can access those interfaces only from files which don't use any libstdc++ headers.

This is only a problem with libstdc++ as far as I know, so I think you can also avoid the problem by using libc++ or something else like that.

Comment: That's a really weird design decision.

Comment: @FUZxxl: I would probably use the word "pathological" but "weird" works.

Comment: Brutal choice!  I just verified this is the case and then accepted your answer.