# why is __STDC_WANT_LIB_EXT2__ needed in C?

Tags: c

On [cpp reference page for strdup](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/experimental/dynamic/strdup), I notice it says,

> As all functions from Dynamic Memory TR, strdup is only guaranteed to be available if `__STDC_ALLOC_LIB__` is defined by the implementation and if the user defines `__STDC_WANT_LIB_EXT2__` to the integer constant 1 before including string.h.

I thought that what the function `strdup` do is just simply `malloc` a space and `strcpy` the source to that space, and I also found its implementation in glibc.

```
char * __strdup (const char *s)
{
  size_t len = strlen (s) + 1;
  void *new = malloc (len);

  if (new == NULL)
    return NULL;

  return (char *) memcpy (new, s, len);
}
```

There's nothing special in its implementation, so why shall I define `__STDC_WANT_LIB_EXT2__` to integer 1 before using `strdup` (or any other Dynamic Memory TR)? What does defining `__STDC_WANT_LIB_EXT2__` do here?

Comment: There are some details here: https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Feature-Test-Macros.html

Comment: Might https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68259832/why-do-we-need-feature-test-macros/68260816#68260816 answer your question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the top of the [page you linked](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/experimental/dynamic/strdup) clarifies,  the `strdup` function was not officially a part of the C Standard Library until C23, which has [not yet been finalized](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n2864.pdf).

Before that, it was available as a "[dynamic memory extension](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/experimental/dynamic)", a set of extensions to the C standard introduced in 2010. Compilers and implementations of the C Standard Library (such as the GNU C Standard Library) which implemented these extensions usually "hid" them behind macros,
such as `STDC_WANT_LIB_EXT2` in this case. See [Feature Test Macros](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Feature-Test-Macros.html) for more Glibc examples of those special feature macros.

---

[`strdup`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strdup.html) in particular has existed long before 2010. as part of the POSIX standard, which glibc implements, and as such you do not need to explicitly define the aforementioned macros if you are using the GNU toolchain.

[See here](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/contents.html) for more examples of POSIX functions.