# Are there scenarios in which defining _POSIX_C_SOURCE can have negative side-effects?

Tags: c

I set out to make my program C99, and so I compile it with the `-std=c99` gcc flag. To make this work, because `usleep()` is deprecated, I have to use `nanosleep()`, which is sorta kinda not really part of C99, and requires you to define `_POSIX_C_SOURCE >= 199309L`.

Now, I am confused about how this affects my program and the compilation, and if it can have weird effects on different distros.

Mainly, my question is if I can leave it like that and trust it to work ok most of the time and not have any weird side-effects, or should I remove it and compile the program as C11?

Comment: If you have no specific reason to be C99 compatible, I would aim for at least C11 (or later) at this point.

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68259832/why-do-we-need-feature-test-macros answer your question?

Comment: `usleep()` isn't a part of C99, or any other version of Standard C, either.  Using `_POSIX_C_SOURCE` means that extensions not defined by POSIX should not be available unless you explicitly enable them somehow.  (I usually use `#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 700` if only because the numbers are easier to remember, but I also use a header to set it.  And I usually compile with either `-std=c99` or `-std=c11` — using the older version where I haven't updated my `makefile` yet.). If you want certain GNU extensions, you'll have to enable them with, for example, `#define _GNU_SOURCE` or something similar.

Comment: Functions that ask the program to *sleep* for a specified amount of time aren't part of the standard because the C language is not interested in policing exactly how an operating systems chooses to schedule its processes. `#define`ing `_POSIX_C_SOURCE` is going to limit the portability of your program, because it will only work on `POSIX`-based operating systems, but `sleep()` is part of the `POSIX` standard so unless you wish to use this program on another operating system someday or have some namespace collisions with the other `POSIX` macros/functions/types you'll be fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Are there scenarios in which defining _POSIX_C_SOURCE can have negative side-effects?

Defining `_POSIX_C_SOURCE` before including (otherwise) standard C library headers causes the headers to declare and define things that are specified by POSIX, in addition to standard C library things they declare and define.

If your program uses any of those POSIX things in a non-POSIX way, it can break. For example, a C program that does not use POSIX is free to declare `nanosleep` in its own way for its own purposes, and including the standard C library headers with that should not cause any problems. However, when POSIX features are requested, there may be conflicts between the POSIX declaration of `nanosleep` and the program’s declaration.