# Why does C99 complain about storage sizes?

Tags: linux, gcc, network-programming, c99, gnu99

This is some code I'm compiling on Linux:

```
#include <net/if.h>

int main() {
  struct ifreq ifr;
}
```

`gcc test.c` is fine.

`gcc -std=gnu99 test.c` is fine.

`gcc -std=c99 test.c` fails with the following error:

```
test.c: In function ‘main’:
test.c:4:16: error: storage size of ‘ifr’ isn’t known
```

What's different about C99 that it doesn't like the definition of `struct ifreq` in Linux?

Comment: I believe my question is a duplicate of this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3875197/std-c99-wtf-on-linux

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It's a chain of consequences of preprocessing and GNU C vs C99.

First up, `net/if.h`:

1. `net/if.h` includes `features.h`
2. Later on, it defines `struct ifreq` inside a `#ifdef __USE_MISC` block.

So:

1. What is `__USE_MISC`? -- it is stuff common to BSD and System V
2. Is it defined at this point? -- We need to check that out in `features.h`

So now, `features.h`:

1. When you use `--std=c99` GCC by default defines `__STRICT_ANSI__` (since thats what C99 is)
2. While preprocessing `features.h`, when `__STRICT_ANSI__` is on, the BSD and System V features don't kick in. i.e. `__USE_MISC` is left undefined.

Back up to `net/if.h`: `struct ifreq` does not even exist after preprocessing! **Therefore, the complaint about storage size**.

You can catch the whole story by doing:

```
vimdiff <(cpp test.c --std=c99 -dD) <(cpp test.c --std=gnu99 -dD)
```

or diff'ing them in any other way (like `diff --side-by-side`) instead of `vimdiff`.

If you want this to cleanly compile with `-std=c99`, you must consider the inclusion of the `_DEFAULT_SOURCE` feature test macro (for glibc versions >= 2.19; for older glibc versions, use either `_BSD_SOURCE` or `_SVID_SOURCE`) so that the required functionality is enabled on top of what is offered by C99.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I just stumbled over exactly the same issue. Is there a way to successfully compile such code with `--std=c99`?

Comment: @michas Yes. You could define either the `_BSD_SOURCE` or the `_SVID_SOURCE` [feature test macro](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Feature-Test-Macros.html) in your C sources.