# Does POSIX if.h require a library to use

Tags: c, linux, posix

Does using the POSIX header file `#include <net/if.h>` require a library to be linked aswell? I get the below error when I use a constant from the header file.

> error: `IFNAMSIZ` undeclared

```
#include <net/if.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    char f[IFNAMSIZ]; // compiler error
    return 0;
}
```

If I need a library, whats the name of it? Something like `gcc -o test test.c -lif --std=c11` is not a valid library. Googling this is turning up nothing which is quite frustrating.

*PS: how do you find out what libraries a POSIX header requires?

Solution: The problem is because I am compiling with `--std=c11`. This question describes the problem and the solution: [Why does C99 complain about storage sizes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10433982/why-does-c99-complain-about-storage-sizes)

Comment: use grep and run it through the lib folder ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a [quick google](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696699/basedefs/net/if.h.html), it seems the name defined is `IF_NAMESIZE`, not `IFNAMSIZ`.

The error you are getting is not from a missing library*, but from a missing definition at the compiler step, which means that the header file does not define `IFNAMSIZ`.

*) If it were a library issue, you'd see linker errors with 'missing external symbol' messages.

Comment: my header file found by doing `locate net/if.h` defines it as `IFNAMSIZ` and using `IFNAMESIZE` results in the same compiler error

Comment: There might be more than one `if.h` header on your system. It doesn't seem like the one that gets included defines `IFNAMSIZ`, because else you wouldn't be getting the error message that you are. In particular, the error you are getting is not from a missing library but from a missing definition at the compilation step.

Comment: @JakeM It's `IF_NAMESIZE` with the underscore.

Comment: Whilst the above answer does fix the narrow problem, it wont work for using any other functions/etc from that header file. The problem is because I am compiling with `--std=c11`. This question describes the problem and the solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10433982/why-does-c99-complain-about-storage-sizes