# timespec not found in time.h

Tags: c, struct

I am having to rewrite an application from C++ to C. I am using gcc and Eclipse on Ubuntu 12.04. In doing so I have come across this error

```
../src/TTNoddy.c: In function ‘main’:
../src/TTNoddy.c:16:2: error: unknown type name ‘timespec’
```

Here is my code snippet that reproduces the problem

```
#include <time.h>

int main(void) {

    timespec TS;
    TS.tv_nsec = 1;

    return 0;
}
```

I am confused here - I am a C++ coder and never written a pure C application in my life, but the man page for `clock_gettime` clearly indicates that `timespec` is found in the `time.h` header file which I am including here. What have I missed?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

timespec is a `struct`, you need to explicitly tell the compiler this. If you carefully read the man page you can see it is stated so.

This should work:

```
#include <time.h>

int main(void) {
    struct timespec TS;
    TS.tv_nsec = 1;

    return 0;
}
```

**Additional note**: If it had been defined as a `typedef struct`, you would not have needed to add the `struct` part manually. But, you should assume that most/all pure C structs are not defined as a `typedef`

Comment: Thanks. I knew it was a struct, it is just coming from C++ where my code works I never knew you had to explicitly declare each timespec with struct first. I guess there will be many differences that I am going to find like this.

Comment: Also note that timespec is not part of C89/C99 but POSIX. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3875197/std-c99-wtf-on-linux

Comment: Actually my mingw32 compiler doesnt define timespec in time.h at all. But rather pthread.h

Answer (score 3):

It should not be just timespec as timespec is a struct. It should be `struct timespec`. Please modify your code accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

I got this error when trying to compile a working project under **Visual Studio 2015**.

The solution was to add `HAVE_STRUCT_TIMESPEC` to the Preprocessor Definitions.

**Through the GUI:** Project Properties (pan) > Property Pages (icon) > Configuration Properties > C/C++ > Preprocessor > Preprocessor Definitions > Edit > Add `HAVE_STRUCT_TIMESPEC`

**Or manually:** Edit each project file and replace each instance of `<PreprocessorDefinitions>` (there can be several per file) with something like:

```
<PreprocessorDefinitions>HAVE_STRUCT_TIMESPEC;WIN32;__GNU_LIBRARY__;_DEBUG;_CONSOLE;_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS;%(PreprocessorDefinitions)</PreprocessorDefinitions>
```

*NB: I found this answer [somewhere on a Github issue](https://github.com/libusb/libusb/issues/63), so I'm posting it here.*

Comment: Also see [Timespec redefinition error](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33557506) and [Timespec :struct type Error c2011](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33114535).

Answer (score 2):

This issue gave me problems for a while, what I ended up doing was defining *struct timespec* in my code. (just copied it over, straight from man [nanosleep](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/nanosleep.2.html))

```
#include <time.h>

struct timespec {
    time_t tv_sec;        /* seconds */
    long   tv_nsec;       /* nanoseconds */
};

int main(void) {
    struct timespec TS;
    TS.tv_nsec = 1;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Wrap it in a namespace and it will be elegant as much as possible.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question but I was having the same problem after upgrading from gcc 6.3 to 7.1. After looking at the changes you have to define _GNU_SOURCE to include struct_timespec.h.