# HOWTO compile encfs4win on windows

Tags: c++, c, windows, encryption, fuse

I am trying to compile [the encfs port for windows](http://members.ferrara.linux.it/freddy77/encfs.html) (also see the [git project](https://gitorious.org/encfs4win)). To be more precise, I have tried to compile it with [MSYS](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/MSYS), with [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com) and with MSVC 2010. I had no success with either of these, each suffering from completely different problems. Before I give a complete rundown of any of these three quests and the issues involved, I wanted to ask if someone compiled this program successfully and could provide a step-by-step guide on how to compile encfs4win from source,  assuming that we start with a completely vanilla windows 7.

Comment: The first thing I notice when I look at the `encfs4win` project page you linked is "*I’m trying to port EncFS project to Windows…. hope this Git repo could help me (and others) to get it done*". In other words, it doesn't seem to be working yet. If this description is accurate it's no wonder you can't compile it.

Comment: @syam He has binaries on the [project homepage](http://members.ferrara.linux.it/freddy77/encfs.html) which I now also linked in my post. That suggests that there is some way to compile it from source to executable, and I thought it should be hidden in the GIT project somewhere.

Comment: Looks that I was wrong then, my bad. The git repo's description seems to be misleading indeed compared to the project home page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have forked the original project to **[EncFS4win Reloaded](https://github.com/kriswebdev/encfs4win-reloaded/tree/master)**. This allows **1-step build** in Visual Studio **2015**: just do `encfs\encfs\encfs.sln` > `Build` > `Build Solution`.

Libraries are pre-built, but you can also re-build in 1-step dokany and rlog. I also provide updated binaries.

This project solves all issues I've struggled with using the **original (non Reloaded)** project (fredy77) and forks (rustyx), including:

- Missing libraries (especially rustyx fork): check you have [dokan-dev/dokany](https://github.com/dokan-dev/dokany), [Win32 OpenSSL](https://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html), [Boost C++](http://www.boost.org/), [rlog](https://code.google.com/p/rlog/) corresponding to the dependency paths
- Unclear build instructions for Boost and Win32 OpenSLL: Do you really need to build these? The official sites provide pre-built libraries (and also build instructions, if you have time to loose or are paranoïd).
- Update encfs > encfs1 properties > C/C++ > Additional Include Directories
- Update encfs > encfs1 properties > Linker > Additional Library Directories
- Update encfs > encfs1 properties > Linker > Input > Additional Dependencies
- [Timespec issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11153334/timespec-not-found-in-time-h/33593026#33593026) in VS2015, in several projects
- And be careful about Debug vs Release builds and libraries.