# Visual Studio error with 'timespec' structure

Tags: c, visual-studio, pthreads

While executing a Pthread program in C using Visual Studio 2015, I got the following error:

**Error C2011   'timespec': 'struct' type redefinition**

The following is my code:

```
#include<pthread.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>


void *calculator(void *parameter);

int main(/*int *argc,char *argv[]*/)
{
    pthread_t thread_obj;
    pthread_attr_t thread_attr;
    char *First_string = "abc"/*argv[1]*/;
    pthread_attr_init(&thread_attr);
    pthread_create(&thread_obj,&thread_attr,calculator,First_string);
        
}
void *calculator(void *parameter)
{
    int x=atoi((char*)parameter);
    printf("x=%d", x);
}
```

Comment: see also here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37072163/719662

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add this compiler flag:

```
-DHAVE_STRUCT_TIMESPEC
```

Comment: but now i have a new problem,  int main(){pthread_create(&threads[t], NULL, PrintHello, (void *)t);}  void *PrintHello(void *threadid){printf("Hello world");pthread_exit(NULL);}  It is a Void method but still its asking me to return value

Answer (score 9):

Despite this question is already answered correctly, there is also another way to solve this problem.

First, problem occurs because `pthreads-win32` internally includes `time.h` which already declares `timespec struct`.

To avoid this error the only thing we should do is this:

```
#define HAVE_STRUCT_TIMESPEC
#include <pthread.h>
```

Answer (score 1):

The same problem happens when compiling programs in Visual Studio 2015 that include MariaDB 10 header files (saw it with 10.1.14).

The solution there is to define the following:

```
STRUCT_TIMESPEC_HAS_TV_SEC
STRUCT_TIMESPEC_HAS_TV_NSEC
```

Answer (score 0):

On Visual Studio 2015.

I solve the problem adding:

```
#define _TIMESPEC_DEFINED
```

Answer (score -6):

**Delete all instances of 'TIMESPEC' in pthread.h** (Make a backup first.)

If I understand it correctly, you probably downloaded pthreads and tried installing it into your VS.

But the pthreads.h file doesn't play nicely with the TIMESPEC defintions already defined in some other header file.

So, delete the portions of the pthreads.h file where TIMESPEC is defined.

Comment: I would strongly recommend not deleting parts of an included header file from a library, this is asking for incompatibility issues in deployment and when working with other developers.

Comment: Deleting from pthread.h could cause problems compiling other programs later on