# Passing HAVE_STRUCT_TIMESPEC directive to the NMAKE command line doesnt fix pthread

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, nmake, pthreads-win32

I am currently trying to build [pthread-win32 from here](https://github.com/vancegroup-mirrors/pthreads-win32) (version 2.7.0). I have the project checked out and can run and view results of `NMAKE VC-static` from the VS2015 developer command prompt. I have an error when building:

> error C2011: 'timespec': 'struct' type redefinition

I think it is solved by adding the preprocessor directive `HAVE_STRUCT_TIMESPEC` ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33114535/timespec-struct-type-error-c2011)).

In order to show correct application of the fix, I decided to silence a warning first. Specifically the warning:

> warning C4996: '_ftime64': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using _ftime64_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details.

This one explicitly tells you to define `_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS`. According to [MS here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hhzbb5c8.aspx) we should use `-D` or `/D` to define preprocessor directives on the command line. I am successfully able to silence the warning by doing:

```
set cl= /D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
nmake VC-static
```

But when I do the same to fix the error:

```
set cl=/DHAVE_STRUCT_TIMESPEC /D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS // or just
set cl=/DHAVE_STRUCT_TIMESPEC
//and
nmake VC-static
```

It is not solved.

**This fix is noted, both on several sources for different libs, in pthread bugfix reports, [and here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33114535/timespec-struct-type-error-c2011), how can i apply this fix in my situation?**

Comment: https://github.com/kaldi-asr/kaldi/issues/595

Comment: Did you try with 2017?

Comment: Thats not the same project and it says you can use the fix i indicated in the question. The issue is i dont know exactly how to apply it.