# pthread 'timespec': 'struct type redefinition

Tags: c, pthreads

I installed pthread just fine onto Visual Studio, but when I try compiling my code I get the

```
'timespec': 'struct type redefinition
```

Where should I be looking to troubleshoot or what did I do wrong?

My code for reference:

```
#include<pthread.h>
#include<stdio.h>


int ready = 0;

void* myThreadFun(void* vargp) {
    printf("Printing from Thread \n");
    return NULL;
}


int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    pthread_t thread_id;
    printf("Before Thread\n");
    pthread_create(&thread_id, NULL, myThreadFun, NULL);
    pthread_join(thread_id, NULL);
    printf("After Thread\n");

}
```

Comment: Apparently it is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33114535/14393739)