# getting an error : error: expected ')' before

Tags: c

### a.h

```
#define print_line(fmt,...) do{\
    struct timespec _t; clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &_t);\
    printf("%ld.%ld %s:%d: " fmt "\n", _t.tv_sec + _t.tv_nsec / 1000000, __func__, __LINE__, ##__VA_ARGS__);\
}while(0)
```

### a.c

```
struct timespec timeval;

print_line(timeval)
```

getting an error : `error: expected ')' before .`

Comment: Did you include `time.h`?

Comment: The error appears somewhere else; mentioned code will not cause such problems. Show us full source of `a.h` and `a.c` if it is possible.

Comment: It seems that you try to use variadic define without `-std=c99` option. However, if you'll add it, you'll get an error about `timespec ` - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3875197/std-c99-wtf-on-linux

Comment: you need a ; after a while(0) ;    or not?

Comment: please, show a litter more of a.c

Comment: @qPCR4vir No, there shouldn't be a semi-colon. Consider `if (...) print_line(timeval); else ...`. While this looks like valid C++ code, it would give a syntax error. [This discussion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/154136/do-while-and-if-else-statements-in-c-c-macros) touches on it, but not directly.

Comment: @Dukeling. Rigth, but Angus show he use the macro Without the ; at end

Comment: @Angus : And struct timespec _t; clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &_t);  is test data too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `"..." fmt "..."` that appears in your `#define` is only valid if `fmt` is a string literal (`"..."`).

I suspect you want something more along the lines of:

```
 #define print_line(fmt,...) do{\
    char str[100]; \
    sprintf(str, "%%ld.%%ld %%s:%%d: %s\n", fmt);\
    printf(str, 1.0 / 1000000, __func__, __LINE__, ##__VA_ARGS__);\
}while(0)
```

Test:

```
char *i = "hello%s";
print_line(i, "abc");
```

Another thing - C has no idea how to convert `struct timespec` to string so you'll need to do something like: (if timespec starts with anything other than a null-terminated char array, it won't work)

```
struct timespec
{
   char abc[100];
};
struct timespec ts;
sprintf(ts.abc, "hello%%s"); // for testing
print_line(&ts, "abc");
```

One more thing - "%ld.%ld" appears to print out rubbish and I'm not entirely sure why. Maybe you want "%f" instead.

Comment: Sorry... what is the meaning of 1.0 / 1000000 in the macro?

Comment: @qPCR4vir That's just some test data

Answer (score 0):

I assumed you whant a debbuging tool with just print the name of the variable you are about to use, with the time in sec and millisec, source code location and some optional comment.

```
#define print_line(fmt,...) do{\
    struct timespec _t; clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &_t);\
    printf("%ld s %ld ms %s:%d: %s" " fmt " "\n", _t.tv_sec , _t.tv_nsec / 1000000, __func__, __LINE__, ##__VA_ARGS__);\
}while(0)
```

use:

```
 struct timespec timeval;
 print_line(timeval) ;
```

Comment: If you want to print the name of the variable, you'll change `fmt` to `#fmt` in the question (your change will just print the string "fmt"), but I assumed `fmt` stood for `format` (and looking at what the `#define` does supports that notion), thus OP probably wants more than just the variable name.

Comment: Hmm… !! OK, I agree. Thank. But then what he originally wrote is very far from that, in both the macro and how he uses it.   I assumed he wanted something else.