# Storage size of timespec isn't known

Tags: c, linux, gnu, c99, timespec

I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3875197/linux-gcc-with-std-c99-complains-about-not-knowing-struct-timespec) solution but I am getting the same errors.  For a class, we had to switch to the c99 compiler instead of gnu but now timespec seems to be broken.  Along with "storage size of timespec isn't known", I am getting a bunch of other errors like "CLOCK_MONOTONIC undeclared", "dereferencing a pointer to incomplete type 'struct timespec'", and unused variable warnings but I assume these would go away once I work out the compiler issue.

I wouldn't imagine there is anything wrong with the way I am declaring timespec variables,

`struct timespec startTime;`

Comment: "we had to switch to the c99 compiler instead of gnu" - That is definitively not a valid reason. gcc supports C99 as well as C11, just learn about the `-std=` option. Another questions why you learn a version of C which has been canceled 6 years ago with the current and only standard C11. Wrt your problem: read [ask] and provide a [mcve]. As it looks now, you seem to access internals of a `struct` you are not supposed to use. Which means your code is broken by design.

Comment: In our new assignment details, he told us specifically to use the flag `-std=c99`.  Sorry, I meant to put this in the description.  I'm not choosing to use this, we have to.  Also could you elaborate on trying to access the internals of a struct.

Comment: In your question you imply you don't use gcc because is it not c99 compliant. But according to your comment you **do use** gcc (contradicting your statement in the question), just with the option I recommend. You should first understand what's going on before programming. And you should read my previous comment carefully and try to understand. This is not a spoon-feeding service!

Comment: It's hard to answer a question like this without code and some basic other information like the OS you're using.

Comment: @Olaf "gnu" is a gcc flag, -std=gnu99.

Comment: If you are told to use C99, use C99. `struct timespec` and `CLOCK_MONOTONIC` are not a part of C99. Use something else.

Comment: @n.m.: As you wrote: `gnu99`, not `gnu`. And that still would be c99, just with the gcc extensions. The rest of the line adds to the confusion, as there is no distinct c99 compiler (`-std=c99` just deactivates the extensions and reports warnings about some of them.

Comment: @Olaf yes OP is using some sloppy terminology, but the message is clear, no need to go full pedantic mode. The extensions *are* the point here. `struct timespec` is one of them.

Answer (score 12):

As this kind of "clock" support isn't C99 but POSIX, it's not enabled by default.

To enable it you want to pass the option `-D_POSIX_C_SOURCE=199309L` to the compiler or put a

```
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 199309L
```

at very beginning of the source file(s) in question.

[See also `man clock_gettime` for reference.](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/clock_gettime.2.html)

Answer (score 0):

Set [C dialect](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C-Dialect-Options.html) flag to GNU dialect of ISO C99:

`-std=gnu99`