# Why does clock_gettime not compile when using C99?

Tags: c99, libc, system-clock

Why does this C code compile in C99? What should I read to learn more?

I can't post unless I add more text so here's some nonsense text because I don't think there's anything else to say

```
$ cat m.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
int main() {
    struct timespec time;
    int res = clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &time);
    printf("%d %ld %ld\n", res, time.tv_sec, time.tv_nsec);
    return 0;
}


$ clang m.c && ./a.out && rm ./a.out
0 1631386905 774654955


$ clang -std=c99 m.c && ./a.out && rm ./a.out
m.c:4:18: error: variable has incomplete type 'struct timespec'
        struct timespec time;
                        ^
m.c:4:9: note: forward declaration of 'struct timespec'
        struct timespec time;
            ^
m.c:5:12: warning: implicit declaration of function 'clock_gettime' is invalid in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
        int res = clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &time);
                ^
m.c:5:26: error: use of undeclared identifier 'CLOCK_REALTIME'
        int res = clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &time);
                                ^
1 warning and 2 errors generated.
```

Comment: does this answer? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3875197/gcc-with-std-c99-complains-about-not-knowing-struct-timespec c11 has it, and some other stuff (posix) has it.  just c99 does not.  enable that other stuff if using c99

Comment: `clock_gettime` is not a part of C99, the code could be compiled either with the GNU99 extension `-std=gnu99`, or with the `#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200112L` macro

Comment: The "invalid in C99" is because without the POSIX feature test macros enabled, `<time.h>` doesn't contain a declaration of `clock_gettime`.  Prior to C99 it was legal (though usually wrong) to use a function even if hadn't been declared; the compiler assumed an *implicit declaration* of the function as returning `int` and taking unspecified arguments.  In C99 this was made undefined behavior, but GCC will still provide the older behavior after giving a warning.  Anyway, you don't want any of that; the right fix is to define the feature test macro and get the proper declaration from `<time.h>`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It’s because using the `-std=c99` option defines a macro that causes the declaration of `clock_gettime` to be hidden.

The GNU C library can expose different versions of its functions, or hide them altogether, depending on what is expected by user code.  User code declares those expectations by defining certain specially-named macros (called *feature test macros*, though this is something of a misnomer) with pre-determined values recognised by the GNU C library headers.  One such macro is `__STRICT_ANSI__`, which is implicitly defined if any of the `-std=cXX` options are used.

Quoting [`feature_test_macros(7)`](https://linux.die.net/man/7/feature_test_macros):

> `__STRICT_ANSI__`
>
> ISO Standard C.  This macro is implicitly defined by [`gcc(1)`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/gcc) when invoked with, for example, the `-std=c99` or `-ansi` flag.
>
> […]
>
> If any of `__STRICT_ANSI__`, `_ISOC99_SOURCE`, `_ISOC11_SOURCE` (since glibc 2.18), `_POSIX_SOURCE`, `_POSIX_C_SOURCE`, `_XOPEN_SOURCE`, `_XOPEN_SOURCE_EXTENDED` (in glibc 2.11 and earlier), `_BSD_SOURCE` (in glibc 2.19 and earlier), or `_SVID_SOURCE` (in glibc 2.19 and earlier) is explicitly defined, then `_BSD_SOURCE`, `_SVID_SOURCE`, and `_DEFAULT_SOURCE` are not defined by default.

Using `-std=gnuXX` option instead of `-std=cXX` does not cause `__STRICT_ANSI__` to be defined; it also enables GNU extensions to the C language.  If you want to keep those language extensions disabled, you can instead put `#define _DEFAULT_SOURCE 1` at the very top of the file to expose all the symbols the C library otherwise would expose (or perhaps another feature test macro to adjust the library interface to your liking).  An explicit feature test macro will take precedence over `__STRICT_ANSI__`.