# Plone 4.2.3 continuously dies then restarts with error "undefined symbol: clock_gettime"

Tags: plone

Installed Plone 4.2.3 as Stand-Alone Zope Instance via unified installer on a
machine running CentOS release 5.9.  That machine's local IP address is
192.168.1.10.  Only change I made in buildout.cfg is:

```
http-address = 192.168.1.10:8080
```

then successfully ran `./bin/buildout` from `/usr/local/Plone-4.2.3/zinstance/`.
No other process listens on port 8080.  Started Plone successfully:

```
# pwd; date; /usr/bin/sudo -u plone /usr/local/Plone-4.2.3/zinstance/bin/plonectl start
/usr/local/Plone-4.2.3
Sun Feb 24 14:12:06 EST 2013
instance: . .
daemon process started, pid=2687
```

Problem is ZServer stops and another starts approximately every 25 to 30
seconds, and so is unuseable.  .../zinstance/var/log/instance.log shows:

```
------
2013-02-24T14:12:31 INFO ZServer HTTP server started at Sun Feb 24 14:12:31 2013
    Hostname: xxxxx
    Port: 8080
------
2013-02-24T14:13:11 INFO ZServer HTTP server started at Sun Feb 24 14:13:11 2013
    Hostname: xxxxx
    Port: 8080
------
2013-02-24T14:13:39 INFO ZServer HTTP server started at Sun Feb 24 14:13:39 2013
    Hostname: xxxxx
    Port: 8080
------
2013-02-24T14:14:09 INFO ZServer HTTP server started at Sun Feb 24 14:14:09 2013
    Hostname: xxxxx
    Port: 8080
```

and more such entries are continuously added to the log file.

In `.../zinstance/parts/instance/etc/zope.conf` I then changed eventlog level
from *INFO* to *ALL* and set "`zserver-threads 1`" then stopped and started Plone.

Again ZServer dies after 25 to 30 seconds, another ZServer starts, it dies
after 25-30 seconds, etc.  All entries in instance.log are DEBUG level.  For a
given ZServer the last log entry is dated approx. 19 seconds after its "INFO
ZServer HTTP server started" entry.  Approx. 8 seconds later the next entry is
another "INFO ZServer HTTP server started".

Question: why the heck is ZServer process dying?

---

Ran server if fg mode and last few errors before ZServer died were:

zope.configuration.xmlconfig.ZopeXMLConfigurationError: File "/usr/local/Plone-4.2.3/zinstance/parts/instance/etc/site.zcml", line 16.2-16.23

ZopeXMLConfigurationError: File "/usr/local/Plone-4.2.3/buildout-cache/eggs/Products.CMFPlone-4.2.3-py2.7.egg/Products/CMFPlone/configure.zcml", line 102.4-106.10

ZopeXMLConfigurationError: File "/usr/local/Plone-4.2.3/buildout-cache/eggs/plone.app.theming-1.0.4-py2.7.egg/plone/app/theming/configure.zcml", line 19.4-19.34

ZopeXMLConfigurationError: File "/usr/local/Plone-4.2.3/buildout-cache/eggs/plone.app.theming-1.0.4-py2.7.egg/plone/app/theming/browser/configure.zcml", line 12.4-18.10

ImportError: /usr/local/Plone-4.2.3/buildout-cache/eggs/lxml-2.3.4-py2.7-linux-i686.egg/lxml/etree.so: undefined symbol: clock_gettime

The clock_gettime error is apparently related to dev plone org tickets:

## 13426 (lxml error: undefined symbol: clock_gettime with Plone-4.2 ...

and

## 13409 (Problem installing Plone 4.2.3 with UnifiedInstaller) – Plone ...

Checked
/usr/local/Plone-4.2.3/buildout-cache/eggs/lxml-2.3.4-py2.7-linux-i686.egg/lxml/etree.so
with nm and only occurence of clock_gettime in output was:

0008a130 T callLookupFallback
         U clock_gettime
         U close

"T" The symbol is in the text (code) section.
"U" The symbol is undefined.

Google search for (linux clock_gettime) found

https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=88108 and

[Ubuntu Linux C++ error: undefined reference to 'clock_gettime' and 'clock_settime'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2418157/ubuntu-linux-c-error-undefined-reference-to-clock-gettime-and-clock-settim)

both of which say adding -lrt to the (end of the) list of libraries you link to
will fix the problem.  I looked at
Plone-4.2.3-UnifiedInstaller/base_skeleton/lxml_static.cfg.  That kind of
make file isn't familiar to me.  Not sure what to do next.

Comment: My favourite is wrong permissions on the blobstorage or filestorage. Do you get more useful info if you start the server in debug mode (i.e. `bin/plonectl fg`)?

Comment: Please run the server in `fg` mode, and tell us what is printed on the console: `/usr/bin/sudo -u plone /usr/local/Plone-4.2.3/zinstance/bin/plonectl start`.

Comment: @pete johnson: I wonder, if including the IP in the 'http-address'-variable, instead of only naming the port as usual, could be a problem. Is there a compelling reason for doing this?

Answer (score 3):

Pick up the latest version of the 4.2.x Unified Installer (4.2.4 at the time of this writing), which has a fix for the libxml2 build on CentOS. Then, use the "--static-lxml" argument on the ./install.sh command line.