# Linking on Ubuntu 12.04 - undefined reference to `clock_gettime@GLIBC_2.17'

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu

I am compiling a C++ project on Ubuntu 12.04 and I get a linking error stating

> undefined reference to `clock_gettime@GLIBC_2.17'
>
> undefined reference to `clock_getres@GLIBC_2.17'

I read a lot of threads about this issue and I tried all the usual solutions (separately). Such as adding the `-lrt` flag to the `g++` command line (I tried in the beginning and in the end), setting the cmake linker flags variables to `-lrt`, adding the librt.so location to the `link_directories` variable or even to the `target_link_libraries`. None of this worked.

When I run `ldd --version` I get

> ldd (Ubuntu EGLIBC 2.15-0ubuntu10.12) 2.15

And for what I understood from research this is the last glibc version for Ubuntu 12.04. But the error references to glibc 2.17...
So My question is: Am I getting this error because of the gclib version? Is there any way I can get a more recent version for Ubuntu 12.04?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Seems like your project needs `libc2.17`. Or could it be the g++ (or gcc) you have installed? The first step would be to determine who needs this newer libc version, and if possible try to make it using `2.15`. According to this [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_C_Library) `Ubuntu 13.04` has it.

Comment: Yes, that's it @CristiFati. I realized which was the library that had this dependency and I asked the software owner for a version compiled using glibc 2.15. It's all working now!

Comment: ecnl or @CristiFati, could one of you write up an answer please?

Answer (score 0):

Although (because the *OS* is ancient) it might no longer apply, writing an answer (as @ecnl didn't visit the site in years).

- Each *OS* (*Nix*) comes up with a [[GNU]: The GNU C Library (glibc)](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc) version which (like any other package) could be upgraded during *OS* lifetime.

  *Ubuntu Precise* (*12.04*), has (at question time) *LibC **2.15*** ([[LaunchPad]: Binary package “libc-bin” in ubuntu precise](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/precise/+package/libc-bin))
- A (3<sup>rd</sup>-party) library (*.so*) used by the project, was built against (and links to) *LibC **2.17***

The root cause of this is that between the 2 versions, *clock_** functions were moved from *LibRT* to *LibC* (as pointed out by [[SO]: C++ error: undefined reference to 'clock_gettime' and 'clock_settime' (@P.P's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32649327/4788546) (and referenced [[SourceWare]: Move clock_* symbols from librt to libc.](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=commitdiff;h=6e6249d0b461b952d0f544792372663feb6d792a;ds=sidebyside))).

As a consequence, an *ELF* linking to *v2.17* will not run on *v2.15*, as it expects those functions to be exported by *LibC*. Possible fixes:

1. Rebuild the *.so* with *v2.15* (option already took by *OP*)
2. Upgrade *LibC* to *v2.17*. However that might trigger some incompatibility issues (other stuff depending on *v2.15* might stop working), so this has to be carefully considered